# Mongoose / MongoDB aggregate filter by multiple date ranges

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with 365 documents. Each document is as follows:

```
{
  date: "2018-11-27T00:00:00.000Z",
  title: "Went to school"
},
{
  date: "2018-11-28T00:00:00.000Z",
  title: "Bought a car"
}
```

I want to filter documents by multiple data ranges.
Example:

1. Show only documents that have been created after `2018-01-04` and before `2018-11-24`
2. Result should not contain documents that were created in interval `2018-05-06` - `2018-06-07` etc

So far I got this:

```
const dates = await Calendar.aggregate(
  [{
      $match: {
        $and: [{
            date: {
              $not: {
                $lte: new Date(2018, 0, 7),
              }

            }
          },
          {
            date: {
              $not: {
                $gte: new Date(2018, 10, 15)
              }
            }
          },
          {
            date: {
              $not: {
                $gt: new Date(2018, 6, 31),
                $lt: new Date(2018, 7, 15)
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        title: 1,
        date: 1
      }
    }
  ]
).sort('date')
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$lte` and `$gte` with the single `date` object in the query

```
Calendar.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "$and": [
      { "date": { "$lte": new Date(2018, 0, 7), "$gte": new Date(2018, 10, 15) }},
      { "date": { "$not": { "$lte": new Date(2018, 0, 7), "$gte": new Date(2018, 10, 15) }}}
    ]
  }}
])
```